# How to deal with missing packages from ubi-8-appstream?

Tags: redhat, containers, redhat-ubi

I'm looking for best practices with Red Hat's sponsored container images: [Universal Base Image](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/introducing-red-hat-universal-base-image), when we need to deploy application using this containers.

A lot of third party apps requires packages from AppStream, and there's clearly a gap between what is shipped in RHEL's AppStream and `ubi-8-appstream`.

We can use the package `harfbuzz` as an example, on a running RHEL 8.5 we have the development packages available:

```
harfbuzz-1.7.5-3.el8.x86_64
harfbuzz-icu-1.7.5-3.el8.x86_64
harfbuzz-devel-1.7.5-3.el8.x86_64
```

But with `ubi-8-appstream` only the runtime package is available, as can be seen directly on its [repo](https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/x86_64/appstream/os/Packages/h/).

In that situation what is the right way to get the development packages? Adding RHEL's AppStream doesn't seems to be a good idea and this will also raise `subscription-manager` issues.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Same here... i need `libaio-devel` and they redhat folks said: "[Today, UBI is really targeted towards cloud native, application developers working with languages like Java, Node.js, Golang, .Net, Perl, Python, Ruby, and PHP. Currently, this request does not fall within the currently approved use cases for inclusion in UBI.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1840667)"

Answer (score -2):

Please see if the following helps:

[Chapter 11. Adding software to a running UBI container](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/building_running_and_managing_containers/index#assembly_adding-software-to-a-running-ubi-container_building-running-and-managing-containers)

Comment: This link leads to a Red Hat login page.